# Trouble creating vertical parallax

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a vertical slide show on scroll. One picture-screen glide over the next one, and then the second over the third, and so on…

HTML/CSS structure looks as following: external container has display property relative. Inside it there are several containers with images with the property fixed, so that they are all as a card deck and you pull card by card from the top.

JavaScript function should load the first pare of image-pages and follow the amount of scrolled distance changing the index of the image-page and changing the z-index of the layer (the top one: 2, the one blow: 1 and so on...)

```js
    var mansDok = []; var paklajAttal = [];
        //  Find all the slides containers
        mansDok = document.getElementsByClassName("slaide");
        //  Find all the slides IDs
        for(i=0; i<mansDok.length; i++) {
            paklajAttal[i] = mansDok[i].id;
        }
        //  Height of the browser window
        var logAugst = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        //  Start function on scrolling the contents
        window.onscroll = function() {vertikSlaidrade()};
        //
        //  Slideshow function
        function vertikSlaidrade() {
            var k = 0; var i = 0, winScroll;
            //  How far the screen been scrolled
            winScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
            //  Change slides while scrolling
            if(winScroll <= logAugst * 1) {
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[k]).style.zIndex = "2";
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[k]).style.position = "relative";
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[k+1]).style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[k+1]).style.position = "fixed";
            } else if(winScroll <= logAugst * 2) {
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[k+1]).style.zIndex = "3";
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[k+1]).style.position = "relative";
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[k+2]).style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[k+2]).style.position = "fixed";
            } else if(winScroll <= logAugst * 2.8) {
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[k+2]).style.zIndex = "4";
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[k+2]).style.position = "relative";
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[k+3]).style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[k+3]).style.position = "fixed";
            } else if(winScroll > logAugst * 2.8) {
                //  Run reset function by the end of slides
                atiestat();
            }
        }
        //  Function to reset the slides properties
        function atiestat() {
            for(var i=0; i<mansDok.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[i]).style.zIndex = "0";
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[i]).style.position = "absolute";
                document.getElementById(paklajAttal[i]).style.display = "none";
            }
            //  Show the first pair of slides
            document.getElementById(paklajAttal[0]).style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById(paklajAttal[0]).style.zIndex = "2";
            document.getElementById(paklajAttal[1]).style.position = "fixed";
            document.getElementById(paklajAttal[1]).style.zIndex = "1";
        }
```

```css
    * {box-sizing: border-box;}
        html, body{
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            background-color: #000;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        main {
            position: relative;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
        /*  Page with slide  */
        .slaide {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 0;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            display: none;
        }
        .slaide img {
            width: 1230px;  /*  Doesn't work below this value !?!?  */
        }
        /*  Empty filler  */
        .tukss {
            display: block;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 1000px; /*  Do NOT reduce this value!!!  */
        }
```

```html
    <main>
            <div class="slaide" id="lapa1" style="display: block;">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slaide" id="lapa2">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slaide" id="lapa3">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax3.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="tukss" id="tukss"></div>
        </main>
```

May be its not the most elegant version of JS code, but everything works perfectly as I wanted. Somehow it doesn’t work if I change the image size below 1230px or to 100% and reduce the width of the browser window. (Images are from W3Schools.com)

I would appreciate if somebody could help me out with this situation.

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment: "if I change the image size below 1230px or to 100% and reduce the width of the browser window.". Is therre anything else I can help you with?

Comment: .slaide img {
        width: 1230px;  /*  Doesn't work below this value !?!?  */
    }

Comment: I can't reduce the size (width) of the image. And I'd like to put some more info on the right side of the screen...

Comment: I'd appreciate any help, please!

Comment: I would but you haven't explained *how* it doesn't work. You **can** reduce the size of the image but how does that affect your code?

Comment: Oh, sorry, may be you missed just the first sentence: "I am trying to create a vertical slide show on scroll." So the slides how animation frozen on scroll... Slideshow means you can't change images on certain action. In this particular case it is scrolling the contents of the window. Thanks again.  :)

Comment: I am a novie in stackOverflow and have kind of a strange expirience. In a week time I asked 3 questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63474047/javascript-vertical-slideshow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529243/javascript2keyframes-in-one), and nobody could answer any of them. There was no uncertenty in any of the questions. I provided complete code for every situation. Does it mean that nobody knows the answer on any of them? Is it a bad time to ask the questions? I am really confused! Sorry for the trouble and thanks to Mr. Ouchane CC, who actually helped me once before

Comment: I think it might be a language barrier @pavels. Back to your question, the code you posted seems to not work very well at every size so it's hard to help you as I don't know what your desired result is